# convert tinyint field as boolean in result using sequelize raw query node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have problem that when I use a raw query in sequelize which is select query the tinyint fields returned are as integers and not as `true`/`false`.

Here is the code:

```
router.route('/').get(function (req, resp) {
    sequelize.query("select * from territory_device", {model: territoryDevice}).then(result => {
        resp.send(result)
    })
})
```

And here is the result I recieve:

[image: the result]

Although I defined the field `is_active` as a boolean in the model it gets returned as an integer and I am using MySQL dialect .

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Please don't post images of code/data** Read [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/data into the post directly.

Comment: thank you chade but this is first time for me to ask here i will take your advice in consideration next time

Comment: try setting default value to true/false

Answer (score 1):

The problem is mysql side. Mysql returns 0 or 1 for boolean datatype. You can change the datatype or just handle 0 or 1 in your program

Comment: I thought there is a way in sequelize to do that

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `{raw: true}`, you can get Sequelize's wrapper and convert the response using `.toJSON()` method on the returned response.

then you will get the tinyint parsed as boolean as long as its DataType.BOOLEAN in Sequelize's model object.

Comment: When I resort to Sql, it's usually because I'm trying to represent something that is NOT a table. The above only works if you have a model... SO - In Sequelize, can you create a model that is not tied to the database? The same way you might create a virtual column in a model?